# Get compass orientation of wgs84 coordinates or polygon

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, google-maps, wgs84

I got a set of wgs84 coordinates to place a polygon on Google Maps. I am wondering if i can use the same coordinates to get a compass direction of the coordinates. I don't need a solution specific for Google Maps, javascript or php. I am just wondering what the right approche would be.

[image: Something like this would be the end result. I understand it needs some sort of algorithm in the background]
Something like this would be the end result. I understand it needs some sort of algorithm in the background

I found [Geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib) and the 'getCompassDirection' function but this function only allows 2 points to create a line and get the bearing(angle) of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any direction information out of a single position coordinate.

Position coordinates don't represent any knowledge about the orientation of an object. Therefore you need something that has direction (i.e. a vector between two coordinates) to calculate compass direction. That's exactly why the function you mentioned asks for two points.

This means you can get a compass direction for any edge of a polygon (by using its two end points), but not for its vertices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just discovered that someone has answered my question, thanks. So i need to create a algorithm that discovers the 2 most right points. (top right, bottom right) and then calculate the compass direction of them? Thanks for getting me somewhere, still searching for a solution.

Comment: Yes, I think that could work. That would give you the direction of the vector between those points. But you could try other pairs of points as well.
For example, if you have a rectangle, then the longer edge of the rectangle corresponds to the direction toward which the rectangle is "streching", but this might not always be the edge between the top right and bottom right points.